# Return value from a mongodb call from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How do I return an array from a mongojs query.
I have the below query executed with nodejs, into a locally running mongodb database. 
Mongojs is handling the transaction. 
My question is; how can I return an array from the below function call.

```
    var databaseUrl = "users";
    var collections = ["users","reports"]; 
    var db = require('mongojs').connect(databaseUrl, collections );

    function usernameFromId(callback){
      db.users.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if(err || !result) console.log("Error");
          else{
           callback(result);
          }
      });
     };


    var x = usernameFromId(function(user){
    return user;
    });

    console.log(x);
```

Here x is undefined, how can I make a return value such that x will be an array where I can access elements by x.name, x.email etc.

This is what is held in the database.

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("4fb934a75e189ff2422855be"), "name" : "john", 
 "password":"abcdefg", "email" : "john@example.com" }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("4fb934bf5e189ff2422855bf"), "name" : "james", 
 "password" :"123456", "email" : "james@example.com" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't usefully `return` with asynchronous functions. You'll have to work with the result within the callback:

```
usernameFromId(function(user){
    console.log(user);
});
```

This is due to the nature of asynchronous programming: "***exit immediately***, setting up a callback function to be called sometime in the future." This means that:

```
var x = usernameFromId(...);
```

is evaluated, in its entirety (including setting `x` to the `undefined` value returned from `usernameFromId`), before the callback is actually called:

```
function (user) {
    return user;
}
```

And, at least with the current standard of [ECMAScript 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Versions), you can't get around this. As JavaScript is single-threaded, any attempt to wait for the callback will only lock up the single thread, keeping the callback and the `return user` forever pending in the event queue.